# How to update data in pivot table with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, pivot-table

First of all, I'm using laravel 5.1. Now, the scenario is; I have an `exam` page where they can click a `button` to take the exam, the action of the button is to `attach` the `exam_id` and `user_id` to the pivot table called `examattempt_user`. Now that we have a record there, I want to save the `grade` of a user after the user submitted the `exam` (clicking the button), and save/update the `grade` into the pivot table where the `exam_id` and `user_id` was saved. Here's my table:

**Pivot table Fields**:
`id` 
`exam_id` 
`user_id` 
`grade`

Comment: You can use sync to update data.

Comment: How? I think the use of `sync` is to add another data.

Comment: Have you created the relations in your models?

Comment: Sync is to update,watch this https://www.udemy.com/best-laravel/learn/v4/t/lecture/6436738?start=0 and https://www.udemy.com/best-laravel/learn/v4/t/lecture/6436742?start=0

Comment: @JoshBolton yes. Followed the right relations.

Comment: @manjunath What are these? the links are the same.